# CPU with integrated GPU UHD Graphics 630 vs separate GPU

Tags: graphics-card, cpu, gpu

**EXPLANATION**

I'm about to build PC from parts. I'm a software developer, so PC will be used for programming purposes mostly (PHP Storm, Visual Studio, Photoshop, Chrome 50+ tabs at time), I'm not a big gamer, but maybe I will try one or other game with a new PC.

My Budget for all parts are around $2300 - $3500.

I'm about to buy `Intel Core i9-10900K 3.7 GHz 10-Core Processor`. pcpartpicker.com says that it has integrated UHD Graphics 630. Have you ideas is it true? I've checked link to amazon website and there I see note `Discrete graphics required` and in newegg.com description says that it has integrated UHD Graphics 630. Is it posssible that the same processor can be with or without integrated GPU?

---

**QUESTION**

Let's say it has integrated UHD Graphics 630. Is it required for my needs? As I mentioned before I'm not a big gamer, but probably will try one or another game.

How this integrated GPU can I compare to separate GPU? Or any separate GPU will be better than integrated? When we reach the point that integrated GPU is not enough anymore?

Or it's better choice to buy separate GPU and CPU without integrated GPU? If that's true what criteria of GPUs matters? How to choose right one?

Comment: Ok, a couple of things. 1. This is one post with sort of multiple questions. One question per post tend to work better on this site.

Comment: 2. Ark.intel.com is a great resource. It states that yes, this has integrated graphics. (see https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/199332/intel-core-i9-10900k-processor-20m-cache-up-to-5-30-ghz.html?wapkw=i9-10900K)

Comment: 3, (and maybe this should have been written longer as an answer). Integrated GPU's have come a long way. For non gaming theyy tend to be sufficient for most things. The only reason to go with a dedicated card are: a) Non build into the CPU. (not relevant in this case), b) You need more performance (e.g. gaming, CUDA, ...)  c) you want to connect multiple monitors (integrated graphics rarely has 3 or 4 outputs for multiple screens).  d) dedicated graphics cards tend to be more modern. E.g. latest DP or latest HDMI version. Relevant for 4K or 8K.

Comment: e) They do slow down your CPU sicne they need part of the bandwidth to the RAM. That probably is in the order of a few % and I expect that more of fastre RAM, faster SSD etc is more efficient use of money than getting a dedicated graphics card